# Python list slicing sequence genetic code

Tags: python, sequence

I have a list and I want to extract the value of each element from a dictionary and I want to return
 to get a new list starting from `AUG` and ending at `'*'` or  an element which doesn't exist in the dictionary.

For example:

```
CodD = {"UUU":"F", "UUC":"F", "UUA":"L", "UUG":"L",
 "UCU":"S", "UCC":"s", "UCA":"S", "UCG":"S",
 "UAU":"Y", "UAC":"Y", "UAA":"*", "UAG":"*",
 "UGU":"C", "UGC":"C", "UGA":"*", "UGG":"W",
 "CUU":"L", "CUC":"L", "CUA":"L", "CUG":"L",
 "CCU":"P", "CCC":"P", "CCA":"P", "CCG":"P",
 "CAU":"H", "CAC":"H", "CAA":"Q", "CAG":"Q",
 "CGU":"R", "CGC":"R", "CGA":"R", "CGG":"R",
 "AUU":"I", "AUC":"I", "AUA":"I", "AUG":"M",
 "ACU":"T", "ACC":"T", "ACA":"T", "ACG":"T",
 "AAU":"N", "AAC":"N", "AAA":"K", "AAG":"K",
 "AGU":"S", "AGC":"S", "AGA":"R", "AGG":"R",
 "GUU":"V", "GUC":"V", "GUA":"V", "GUG":"V",
 "GCU":"A", "GCC":"A", "GCA":"A", "GCG":"A",
 "GAU":"D", "GAC":"D", "GAA":"E", "GAG":"E",
 "GGU":"G", "GGC":"G", "GGA":"G", "GGG":"G",}
```

with input list:

```
['UAU', 'AUG', 'AAA', 'UAG', 'CAA', 'GUU', 'UUA', 'UUU', 'AAA', 'UAA', 'GGG',
 'UUU', 'AAA', 'UAC', 'AUU', 'ACA', 'CAU', 'AAC', 'AUU', 'UAG', 'ACU', 'UAG',
 'GGG', 'AUG', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'ACC', 'AAA', 'AAC', 'CAG', 'UUU', 'GUU', 'ACU',
 'UAA', 'CAU', 'GGC', 'AUU', 'GGG', 'CAG']
```

the result would be

```
['M','K']
['M','K','K','T','K','Q']
```

These are formed by:

1. Finding the first `'AUG'` element in the list, this starts an output sequence
2. Add each result of `CodD[element]` to the output sequence
3. An output sequence ends if `CodD[element]` doesn't exist, or is `'*'`.
4. go back to 1. until the input list is exhausted

It doesn't matter if `'AUG'` is found again during such a sequence, once started.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't quite follow how the list input results in the two lists outputs.

Comment: Here's my understanding: 1) Find an `AUG` element. 2) map each element to their value in the `CodD` dictionary, add that value to the output list. 3) if there is no such key in the dictionary, or the value is `'*'`, end that output list. Is this correct?

Comment: What should happen if there are *two* `AUG` elements in a sequence? Say the list contains `'AUG', 'something else', 'AUG'`? Should a new sequence be started or should the current one continue?

Comment: the program should look for AUG to start extracting values from the dictionnary and store them in a new list each , it stops when finding the values '*' (key :  UAG , UGA , UAA)  or an element that isnt key or doesnt exist in the dictionary u get it ?

Comment: yes correct.... if the first AUG is the start doesnnt matter if there's an AUG follows

Comment: Shouldn't the second output be `['M', 'K', 'K', 'T', 'K', 'N', 'Q', 'F', 'V', 'T']`? `'CAG'` maps to `'F'`, not to `'*'`; it is the later `'ACU'` that maps to `'*'` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generator:

```
def sequences(mapping, lst):
    result = None
    for elem in lst:
        if elem == 'AUG' and result is None:
            # start a new list
            result = []
        if result is None:
            # not currently creating an input sequence, ignore this element
            continue
        value = mapping.get(elem)
        if value is None or value == '*':
            # sequence end
            yield result
            result = None
            continue
        result.append(value)
```

Demo:

```
>>> # I named your list 'sample' here
...
>>> for result in sequences(CodD, sample):
...     print result
...
['M', 'K']
['M', 'K', 'K', 'T', 'K', 'N', 'Q', 'F', 'V', 'T']
```

Comment: The mapping  Should i put it in the shell or in my python file ? and the'' for result in sequences(CodD, sample):
...     print result"  where shpuld i put it as well ?

Comment: @MunaAr: I showed that the function worked as expected in my shell. You don't have to repeat the demo verbatim, but if you want to use the function I produced, you'd want to use it in a similar way.

Comment: thats what i did and it shows the error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    for result in sequences(CodD, lstTriple):
NameError: name 'CodD' is not defined
>>>

Comment: @MunaAr: you do need to define your own dictionary still! I used the name you used in your question.

Comment: but its is the same as my dictionnary and i put it with the function  heres the code

Comment: @MunaAr: you got a name error because you didn't define that name. That's not a bug in my function, but a problem with the code where you call it.

Comment: it is the same as yours included the dictionnary in the function thats all

Comment: @MunaAr: if you included the dictionary in the function, it no longer needs to be passed in as an argument. Remove the `mapping` parameter from the function definition, and call the function with just the list being passed in.

Comment: okay it'd be better passed in the function  , so what i need to do is  to put the function in a python file , and in the shell I put the dictionnary (press enter) and  then put for ..... and press (enter again )?

Comment: Im sorry so sorry for my dumb questions i cant get it together

Comment: @MunaAr: you can put the dictionary in a python module too, you don't have to put those in the Python shell. The `...` is just the shell showing it can accept more lines still for the statement you are building. You don't have to enter those yourself.